# How to retrieve data from different page angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a button in the table in the first page. When I click on the button, I want to save the panel Id and display on the next page. How can I call the data in angular? I'm desperately seeking for help since I'm stuck in there for almost a week now.
These are the images for my problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Io4Y.png)
So this one is the first page, where there are buttons in each row.

After clicking Assign, it should show readonly data of ship name and panel name.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEYjY.png)

Comment: Can you please your current code? Also angularjs and angular are different frameworks please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your issue, you should get the panel_id from params in the URL.

E.g.
In the routing of the assigning page, you just set the path:

```
{
     path: 'assigning/:id',
     component: <YourComponent>
}
```

So you can get the panel_id by using `ActivatedRoute`.

Comment: this one I've already tried..but it's not working.

Comment: Sad, what's happened after you clicked on the Assign button? navigate to the assigning page or keep that page and change the view?

Comment: If using workflow between 2 special pages, just use as my suggestion. Or you just need to resolve your code in your component when using 1 page for solving this (not related to your question).

Comment: If I write this code, the assigning page doesn't show up at all.. and it's just white blank.

Comment: Wew, this code just an example for explaining to you. I think you should learn more and know what's you doing

Answer (score 0):

On click event of "Assign" button, you can pass the value to the ts component. In the ts file you can pass it via URL route as a parameter to the next page or store it in localStorage and read from the next page.

```
  <button (click)="passValue(value)">Assign</button>
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to store in local storage and read from next page?

Comment: localStorage.setItem('panelValue', ' value']);in the first page, then in the next page localStorage.getItem('panelValue');